# Nested Functions Java Script

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(st) {

    function y(st){
            if(st=="company")
                return "active";
            else
                return"";
    }

    return '<ul>'+'<li class='+y+'>Company Details</li>'+'</ul>'

}
</script>
```

```
<div class="span3" id="sidebar">

                <script>
                    document.write(myFunction('company'));
                </script>
</div>
```

I have a javascript function myFunction() which returns a string, the string inturn has a function which returns a part of a string depending on input. By using the above code i am getting

```
    <li class="function" y(){return="active";}> Company Details </li>
```

instead

```
    <li class="active">Company Details </li>
```

Thanks

Comment: You aren't calling the function `y()`. Do `return '<ul>'+'<li class='+y('company')+'>Company Details</li>'+'</ul>'` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the function `y` like this:

```
return '<ul>'+'<li class='+y(st)+'>Company Details</li>'+'</ul>'
```

Otherwise you just concatenate the string representation of the function into your HTML markup.